# How can I check if a job exists in Hangfire before I delete it?

Tags: c#, hangfire

Hangfire hangs if you try and delete a job that doesn't exist, i.e if jobId isn't in Hangfire.Job

```
BackgroundJob.Delete(jobId);
```

Is there any way of checking if a job exists before trying to delete it?

Comment: There is no more infinite loop since the latest [1.5.4](http://hangfire.io/blog/2016/03/22/hangfire-1.5.4.html) release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to do this anymore, as the bug causing Hangfire to hang has been fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Try using the monitoring API (`JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi()`), there is a possibility to get job details or list of jobs.

Complete code example:

```
var monitoringApi = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();

var deletedJobs = monitoringApi.DeletedJobs(0, 10);
```

If you want to get queued items:

```
// If no queue name was defined somewhere, probably this will be "default".
// If no items have been queued, then the queue won't exist, and it will error here.
var queue = monitoringApi.Queues().First().Name;

var enqueud jobs = monitoringApi.EnqueuedJobs(queue, 0, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've actually gone with a different workaround for the time being, and created a pull request in hangfire (https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/pull/535) , to fix a bug causing it to hang when an attempt is made to delete a job which doesn't exist.